# POST from current JSP to Servlet values from a previous JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post

**Intro:** 
Serveral Servlets included in JAVA Web Application.
There are some values which are used for all servlets, while other are relevants only for specify servlets.
Therefore, One input form (JSP) used, and then it post these values/form input  to another "new" JSP. From this JSP, values from previous form (JSP) should be posted to a servlet (-sometimes, with in additional values from the new form.)

Using a simple HTML Form, Values from JSP successfully posted to another JSP.

**The Problem:**
Like to send the values (input strings) from previous JSP to a JAVA servlet (using POST method) using the "second" JSP. But failed, as they didn't send from the "second" JSP to the Servlet, even that the "second" JSP could get them from the "first" JSP.

First JSP:

```
 <form name="calca" action="math.jsp" method="POST">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Number1" value="0" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="Number2" value="0" />
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" />
    </form>
```

Second JSP: (math.jsp)

```
  <form name="calcsum" action="PlusServlet" method="POST">
        <% String Number1 = request.getParameter("Number1"); %>
        <% String Number2 = request.getParameter("Number2"); %>
        <br>
        <span>Number1= <%= Number1 %> from calc.jsp form. </span>
        <br>
        <span>Number2= <%= Number2 %> from calc.jsp form. </span>
        <br><br><br><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Plus-Calc" name="Plus-Calc" />
        </form>
```

Servlet process request:

```
String num1=request.getParameter("Number1");
String num2=request.getParameter("Number2");
```

The result: Values posted between the first JSP to the second JSP, but not from the second JSP to the Servlet.

How values from previous form/jsp could be "sent"/post to a servlet using the "second" jsp?

Comment: If you want your form post to include a given parameter then there needs to be an <input> element in the form that corresponds to that parameter.  You can use `type='hidden'` to provide for this without rendering any representation of those parameters.  Do note that the end user in any case has as much control as he wants to exercise over the data that he submits, so you must not consider the parameter values obtained from hidden elements any safer than any others.

Comment: Thank you. 
*Is there another simple method to POST parameters from JSP set with values from a previous JSP without using HTML form? but still with POST,  e.g. using some "forward" session and calling to a servlet?

Comment: I think this might work for you: request.getRequestDispatcher("newUrl?" + request.getParameter("Number1")).forward(request,response);

Comment: this will forward your request to servlet without submitting the form

Comment: You could consider setting the data you want to share as session attributes, so that you don't need to forward through the intermediary JSP(s) at all.  That's a particularly good approach if you don't want to expose them to inspection or manipulation by the client.

Comment: Have tried this: "<a href="<%request.getRequestDispatcher("PlusServlet" + request.getParameter("Number1")).forward(request,response);%>Plus Servlet"</a>" to be tested as a a replacement for POST with a form. Actual result: once jsp with this line loaded, got HTTP 404 since it's auto' run the request, in addition to a random num' to the URL. e.g.: "/PlusServlet2".

Comment: Have tried the set session attributes using this:
  <%session.setAttribute("Number1",Number1);%>
        <%session.setAttribute("Number2",Number2);%>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PlusServlet">Plus Servlet</a>
But between JSP to Servlet it didn't work, so I will stay with the form+POST at this moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put them in hidden fields like this in the form:

```
<form name="calcsum" action="PlusServlet" method="POST">
        <% String Number1 = request.getParameter("Number1"); %>
        <% String Number2 = request.getParameter("Number2"); %>
        <br>
        <span>Number1= <%= Number1 %> from calc.jsp form. </span>
        <br>
        <span>Number2= <%= Number2 %> from calc.jsp form. </span>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <input type="hidden" value="<%= Number2 %>" name="Number1" />
        <input type="submit" value="Plus-Calc" name="Plus-Calc" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="hidden" name="number1" value="<%=request.getParameter("Number1")%>" />
 <input type="hidden" name2="number2" value="<%=request.getParameter("Number2")%>" />
```

add hidden input fields to your form that will submit the data to servlet

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, others who answered above are right. You need to remember that Only form elements are sent when you "HTTP POST" a request. If you do not add hidden fields, numbers you printed are just texts. 
Cheers,

Comment: Great to know. Thanks.